# Running a query with cast and alias - not working

Tags: sql

I have this query I am trying to run, and I keep getting an error. Could be somethign related to the alias, but I think this seems correct?

```
SELECT user_key, playerslevel
FROM data_lab.vw_ft_Game_Progression a
INNER JOIN data_lab.vw_progress b on a.rock_key = b.rock_key
WHERE user_key = 21111119 AND type = 'Level'
AND (CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progression, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER)) as playerslevel < 15
```

ERROR: Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3707 : 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a 'SUCCEEDS' keyword or a 'MEETS' keyword or a 'PRECEDES' keyword or an 'IN' keyword or a 'CONTAINS' keyword between ')' and the 'as' keyword.

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Just get rid of `as playerslevel`.  You do not need to alias it in your `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of `as playerslevel`. You do not need to alias it in your `WHERE` clause.

Result:

```
SELECT 
     user_key, 
     playerslevel
FROM 
     data_lab.vw_ft_Game_Progression a
INNER JOIN 
     data_lab.vw_progress b 
ON 
     a.rock_key = b.rock_key
WHERE 
     user_key = 21111119 
     AND type = 'Level'
     AND (CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progression, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER)) < 15;
```

**Based on your comment**
If you just want to get the number you can do this:

```
DECLARE @test_level VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT 'Level 15');

DECLARE @int_pos INT = (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', @test_level, 0));

SELECT @int_pos;

SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@test_level, @int_pos, LEN(@test_level)-1) AS INT);
```

So in your case you can do:

```
SELECT 
     user_key, 
     playerslevel
FROM 
     data_lab.vw_ft_Game_Progression a
INNER JOIN 
     data_lab.vw_progress b 
ON 
     a.rock_key = b.rock_key
WHERE 
     user_key = 21111119 
     AND [type] = 'Level'
     AND CAST(SUBSTRING(game_progression, CHARINDEX(' ', game_progression, 0), LEN(game_progression)-1) AS INT) < 15;
```

Comment: Hi! I tried that as well, but then I get an error that says it contains a bad character.

Comment: The column game_progression is a string and I am trying to get rid of the word level and only have the numbers that are less than 15.

Comment: The column game_progression is: Level 1, Level 20, Level 5, Level 30, and I only want the number itself.

Comment: @Charlie - You don't need REGEXP for that, if you always have a value like Level X then you can simply get the number using a `CHARINDEX`.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Am I only running the second query you posted? Or the declare functions as well? I followed your second query, but I keep getting an error that says "expected something between '(' and a string or a unicode character literal'

Comment: @Charlie - is this sql server or mysql ?  My code is for sql server, you should indicate that in your tags so we know.  Stating 'sql' isn't enough as some of these functions are specific to SQL Server.  You would only be running the second part in sql server management studio, and it works for me.

Comment: @Charlie - Did you ever figure this out ?